# MultiDownloading with AsyncTask

Tags: android, performance, asynchronous, android-asynctask, lag

I want to download all the files at the same time(simultaneously) with AsyncTask.

I would like to figure out how to download multiple files simultaneously. I tried to search on the internet but found nothing, but found that in a lot of applications this can be done.

I also want to improve the stability of my app (android) so that every time I perform or refresh the UI does not slow down the process ---> "lag".

Excuse my English but do not speak it very well.thank you very much.

Comment: use `executorOnExecutor`.  for parrallel execution `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "http://url.com/image.png")`

Comment: You should look at this training exercise (it does it with images so you will have to adapt it for files in general but points you in the right direction): http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Can you explain an example please? for 2 download in simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your download task like this:

```
public class NewspaperDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {

    URL urlToDownload;

    public DownloaderTask(URL urlToDownload) {
        this.urlToDownload = urlToDownload;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // prepare your download here
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do your download here
        [...]
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(File downloadedFile) {
        // Do something with the download
    }
}
```

If you don't know how to download files in AsyncTask on Android, have a look at my examples i provided [here](https://www.open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=54).

And finally call your downloads like this:

```
// Task 1
DownloadTask task1 = new DownloadTask(urlToDownload);
task1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
// Task 2
DownloadTask task2 = new DownloadTask(urlToDownload);
task2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
// Task 3
DownloadTask task3 = new DownloadTask(urlToDownload);
task3.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

**UPDATE**

Download url from List:

```
List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
urls.add(...);
[...]
for(URL url : urls) {
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask(url);
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

Comment: and If I do not know how many downloads I want to run at the same time?

Comment: See my update, e.g. if you use a list of urls to be downloaded and the number is unknown, just create a task for each url in the list.

Comment: Keep in mind that the number of simultaneously running AsyncTask is not unlimited, so if the number of the system defined maximum pool size threads are already running, a new task will be queued till a running task is finished.

Comment: have you got an example for me? i don't capish very well

Comment: I resolved but i have a problem

Comment: Ok for what exactly you want an example? Downloading a file in a AsyncTask or how to use it? The code above should make it clear how to create multiple tasks.

Comment: Downloading a file in AsyncTask in simulataneos more Download

Comment: here is an complete example to download a file: http://pastebin.com/aNKciJjL  Paste it in an Java class file and the use the task as explained aboce in my update

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `AsyncTask` may not give you the true parallelism that you need. The point is that across different versions of Android, the number of `AsyncTasks` that can run simultaneously has been changed from 1 to 5 and then back to 1 if I remember correctly. Check here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commits/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

and here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M

Moreover `AsyncTasks` may be killed or may not even run. This is due to the fact that `AsyncTasks` are backed by a `ThreadPool` over which you have no control. The best solution, if `AsyncTask` doesn't fit your needs, is to use `Services` or `Loopers` or build your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`.